# Folium Geojson: how to Change a Marker Icon

Tags: python, geojson, folium, markers

This is one of my map layers - Points. I want them to be with my custom markers:

```
fg_other_atms = folium.FeatureGroup(name="Other ATMs", show=False)
        
geometry = gpd.points_from_xy(atm_other.longitude, atm_other.latitude)
geo_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(atm_other[['latitude', 'longitude', 'city_id', 
                                     'region_id', 'trans_cnt','trans_amt']],
                                      geometry=geometry)
geo_df = geo_df.set_crs(epsg=4326, inplace=True)
icon = folium.features.CustomIcon('Icons/red.png', icon_size=(26, 35))
gjson = folium.GeoJson(geo_df, 
                       show=(map_index == 0), 
                       name=lgd_txt.format(txt=map_to_display, col='black'),
                       popup=folium.features.GeoJsonPopup(fields['trans_amt','trans_cnt'],
                       aliases=['Сумма', 'Кол-во']),
                       **marker=folium.features.Marker(icon=icon)**
                                )
fg_other_atms.add_child(gjson)
```

So, without that string in GeoJson - marker=folium.features.Marker(icon=icon) - the layer is drawn with simple markers. I want to replace them with a custom icon but when I add the string above - the layer disappears. How to perform it correctly? Or at least how to change the color of the standard icon?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To change the color of the marker, see [this](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/quickstart.html#Markers). Also, for custom icons, see [this](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/blob/main/examples/CustomIcon.ipynb).